# Diff two yaml files using python

Tags: python, yaml, diff

How can I do diff of two YAML files and generate base on this comparison new file?
For example:

```
users:
- login: user1
  first_name: MyUser1
  last_name: MyUser1
  groups:
    - admin
    - db
    - hr
- login: user2
  first_name: MyUser2
  last_name: MyUser2
  groups:
    - admin
    - hr
```

and second version of file (removed group admin):

```
users:
- login: user1
  first_name: MyUser1
  last_name: MyUser1
  groups:
    - db
    - hr
- login: user2
  first_name: MyUser2
  last_name: MyUser2
  groups:
    - admin
    - hr
```

and get something like(with only difference):

```
users:
- login: user1
  groups:
    - admin
```

If someone will remove full section for example user1 so:

```
users:
- login: user2
  first_name: MyUser2
  last_name: MyUser2
  groups:
    - admin
    - hr
```

i need to only have result like:

```
removed_users:
  user1
```

or simply nothing the most important is when group for user is removed

Comment: Why would `login: user1` be in the difference?

Comment: @anthon because then i want to use this data in ansible commands. thats why i need to have info that user1 was removed from group: admin

Answer (score 1):

What you need is small recursive routine:

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import ruamel.yaml

file_1 = Path('input.yaml')
file_1.write_text("""\
users:
- login: user1        # keep
  first_name: MyUser1
  last_name: MyUser1
  groups:
    - admin
    - db
    - hr
""")

file_2 = Path('changed.yaml')
file_2.write_text("""\
users:
- login: user1   # keep
  first_name: MyUser1
  last_name: MyUser1
  groups:
    - db
    - hr
""")

def difference(d1, d2, keep=[]):
    if isinstance(d1, dict):
        assert isinstance(d2, dict)
        to_delete = set()
        for k, v in d1.items():
            if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
                difference(v, d2[k], keep=keep)
                continue
            if k in keep:
                continue
            if k in d2:
                to_delete.add(k)
                difference(v, d2[k], keep=keep)
        for k in to_delete:
            del d1[k]
             
    elif isinstance(d1, list):
        assert isinstance(d2, list)
        to_delete = set()
        for idx, elem in enumerate(d1):
            if isinstance(elem, (dict, list)):
                difference(elem, d2[idx], keep=keep)
            elif elem in d2:
                to_delete.add(elem)
        for elem in to_delete:
            d1.remove(elem)
    return d1                
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.indent(sequence=4, offset=2)
data1 = yaml.load(file_1)
data2 = yaml.load(file_2)

result = difference(data1, data2, keep=['login'])
yaml.dump(result, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
users:
  - login: user1      # keep
    groups:
      - admin
```

As you can see the comment is preserved, and it could actually be tested upon (instead
of providing 'login' as parameter).

Since your output  has irregular indentation (sometimes the sequence element indicator has no offset
sometimes it has two offset), ruamel.yaml cannot exactly generate what you want, as all sequences in
the output will have the same indent when using ruamel.yaml. This should not matter if
the program processing the output uses a normal YAML parser (just as it doesn't matter for the input).

(Of course you don't need to write the input files as done in this example if you already have
them on your drive)

Comment: Please note that `data1` is modified during this process. If you need it unmodified either make a deepcopy or just load the file once more.

Comment: it is possible to ignore or print if all values are removed from users ? 
now i getting `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @luki you can just put that  line in a `try:  exept IndexError: continue` block

Comment: added but it's not help me becasue i get in result rest of my file from line where user was romoved without comparison with second one ;/ i need to found other solution

Comment: That is strange because my program gets exactly the output that you asked for in your question (the part after "which gives' is the actual output from running the python program). Maybe your question was incorrect?

Comment: yes it is, when i removing line from groups i get nice output. but when i did test for full user section so i changed second file like (removed lines with //): `users: - login: user1          first_name: MyUser1   last_name: MyUser1   groups:     - admin //- login: user2    //  first_name: MyUser2 // last_name: MyUser2 //  groups: //    - admin //  `  - db i getting error IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: so i need only diff on group and if user is removed with all values is not important for me, or can be in second section of the result

Answer (score 0):

Like what @Anthon said : login : user1 is not a missing data.
You need to convert yaml to dict and after you use `deepdiff` with ignoring the order to get expected result like as below :

```
import yaml
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

def yaml2dict(yamlFile):
    dict_res = {}
    with open(yamlFile, 'r') as fp:
        datax = yaml.safe_load_all(fp)
        for data in datax:
            for key, value in data.items():
                dict_res[key] = value
    return dict_res

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = yaml2dict(r'C:\Users\Desktop\1.yaml')
    b = yaml2dict(r'C:\Users\Desktop\2.yaml')
    ddiff = DeepDiff(a, b, ignore_order=True)
    print(ddiff['iterable_item_removed'])
```

**Output :**

```
{"root['users'][0]['groups'][0]": 'admin'}
```

Comment: yes i have something similar but there is possiblity to have not item.index[0] but key name ? 

`{"root['users'][0]['groups'][user1]": 'admin'}`